Layer from database taking long time to load on QGIS project
I have a layer in a PostgreSQL database that I put in a Qgis project. The problem is that it's taking a long time to load, despite having created an index for the geometry using gist and for other various atributes. I note that the layer in itself is just the departemental limits of France.

I put it on a Qgis project, that has a lot of layers, but I don't think it could affect the layer that badly.
I also used a set of rules for the symbology, like in the following image, but with 3 other groups.


You don't seem to have an index on the actual column used in the query (friche_statut), but the best thing to do is work out what the query is (logs) and then run explain on it
